# How to check if user exist in local storage

Tags: javascript

I have this class project to build a user registration and login form that stores data using local storage. If a new user registers it stores their email address and password in localStorage which is working as expected.

But I am finding it difficult to compare data when a user that is not registered tries to login and when a user that is registered tries to login.

If a user is registered and tries to login it should compare the input value with the stored data in localStorage and alert "login Successful" else "Not a registered user".

I am using JavaScript to do this. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
var userData;
var usersr;
var loginData;
var usersl;
// For user registration 
const registerBtn = document.getElementById('register-btn')

function UserRegistration() {
  userData = [{
    email: document.getElementById('register-email').value
  }, {
    password: document.getElementById('register-pass').value
  }];
  usersr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
  usersr.push(userData);
  localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(usersr));
  location.reload()
  console.log(userData)
}
// For user login 
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login-btn')

function loginUser() {
  usersl = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UsersLogin')) || [];
  loginData = [{
    loginEmail: document.getElementById('login-email').value
  }, {
    loginPass: document.getElementById('login-pass').value
  }];
  usersl.push(loginData)
  localStorage.setItem('UsersLogin', JSON.stringify(usersl))
  console.log(usersl)
  location.reload()
}
```

Comment: You are not checking if the user is actually registered or not, to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of unnecessary code in there. You can use these functions to make it work:

```
function userRegistration() {
    const userData = {
        email: document.getElementById('register-email').value,
        password: document.getElementById('register-pass').value
    };
    localStorage.setItem('UsersLogin', JSON.stringify(userData));
    window.location.reload();
}

function loginUser() {
    const loginEmail = document.getElementById('login-email').value
    const loginPass = document.getElementById('login-pass').value
    if (localStorage.getItem('UsersLogin')) {
        const loginDeets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UsersLogin'))
        if (loginEmail === loginDeets.email && loginPass === loginDeets.password) {
            console.log('Login successful')
        } else {
            console.log('Wrong credentials')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Not a registered user')
    }
}
```

In this login function you first need to check if there even *is* a `UsersLogin` property in the `localStorage`. If there is, then check if the inputs match whatever is stored in that `UsersLogin` property. If it matches, then say "Login Successful" if it doesn't match then say "Wrong credentials". If there is no `UsersLogin` property in the `localStorage` at all then say "Not a registered user".

> **UPDATE AS PER REQUEST:**

If you want to keep the previously registered users in the `localStorage` and just update the `UsersLogin` property to include the the newly registered user then you can do it like so:

```
function UserRegistration() {
    let storedUsers = localStorage.UsersLogin ? JSON.parse(localStorage.UsersLogin) : [];
    const userData = {
        email: document.getElementById('register-email').value,
        password: document.getElementById('register-pass').value
    };
    storedUsers.push(userData);
    localStorage.setItem('UsersLogin', JSON.stringify(storedUsers));
    window.location.reload();
}

function loginUser() {
    const loginEmail = document.getElementById('login-email').value
    const loginPass = document.getElementById('login-pass').value
    if (localStorage.getItem('UsersLogin')) {
        const allStoredUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UsersLogin'));
        const matchedUser = allStoredUsers.filter(user => {
            return loginEmail === user.email && loginPass === user.password;
        })
        if (matchedUser.length) {
            console.log('Login successful')
        } else {
            console.log('Wrong credentials')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Wrong credentials') // Don't say "Not a registered user"
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** You might have to clear the `localStorage` for the new functions
>   to work, because `localStorage.UsersLogin` is now an `array` where it used to 
>   be an `object`, so it might throw an error if you don't clear it
>   first. Just run `localStorage.clear()` in the console.

Also, I know I did this in the first block of code, but don't tell the user if a user profile exists or not (Don't log "Not a registered user"), because it's a security flaw. It hints to the user about who is in your database and who is not. This is valuable information to a hacker or malicious actor. Instead just say "Wrong credentials" again.

Comment: still have one more questions @Ludolfyn, How do keep the registered user data unchanged in local storage so that when a new user tries to register the previous registered user data still remains there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem at all @SamsonUgwu  I updated the answer as per your request. I hope it helps!

Comment: Bro u are three (3) much, Thanks man u really saved me a all lots of headache.@Ludolfyn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have made this code to register, now you can write your code to login, I took care of user duplication

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us"></html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Register</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <form onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email"><br>
    <input type="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="register">
  </form>

  <script>
    var emailElement = document.querySelector("[type='email']"),
      passwordElement = document.querySelector("[type='password']");

    if(!localStorage["UsersAuth"]) {
      localStorage["UsersAuth"] = "{}";
    }

    document.querySelector("[type='submit']").onclick = function() {
      var registeredUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage["UsersAuth"]);
      if(emailElement.value in registeredUsers) {
        alert("This email is already registered!");
      }else {
        registeredUsers[emailElement.value] = passwordElement.value;
      }
      localStorage["UsersAuth"] = JSON.stringify(registeredUsers);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
// For user registration 
const registerBtn = document.getElementById('register-btn')

function UserRegistration() {
  var userData = {
    email: document.getElementById('register-email').value,
    password: document.getElementById('register-pass').value
  };
  var usersr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
  if(!usersr.some(user => user.email === userData.email)) {
   usersr.push(userData);
   localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(usersr));
   location.reload()
   console.log(userData)
  }
  else {
    //email already registered
  }
}

// For user login 
const loginBtn = document.getElementById('login-btn')

function loginUser() {
  var usersl = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UsersLogin')) || [];
  var usersr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
  var loginData = {
    loginEmail: document.getElementById('login-email').value,
    loginPass: document.getElementById('login-pass').value
  };
  var currentUser = usersr.filter(user => user.email === loginData.loginEmail);
  if(currentUser.length > 0) {
    //current email is registered
    if(currentUser[0].password === loginData.loginPass) {
      //password do not match 
      return;
    }
    if(!usersl.some(user => user.email === loginData.loginEmail)) {
      // currently not logged in, so login
      usersl.push(loginData);
      localStorage.setItem('UsersLogin', JSON.stringify(usersl))
      console.log(usersl)
      location.reload()
    }
    else {
      // currently logged in
    }
  }
  else {
    // not registered email
  }
}
```